# Treat local file URL as uploaded file

Tags: javascript, file-upload, filereader

Is there a way to treat a local file (on the server) as if it was uploaded? Like fetch the file contents and put it in a array like it was a uploaded file?

So I could use it like

```
var file = someFunctionToRetrieveFile( url );
var re = /(?:\.([^.]+))?$/;

var name = file.name;
var ext = re.exec( name )[0];
var type = file.type;
```

? Is this possible in JavaScript?

Comment: yeah, it's possible, it's called ajax...

Comment: Yes, AJAX can get the file contents... but appending them to the same array structure? Do you have to read the headers and sort all the data that way? I don't think you understand the question.

Comment: you can use xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Type"), along with content-length, and last-modified. File()s don't have any other consistent meta afaik... [].push({...})'ing an object set with these headers and the response or responseText will give you something you can treat like a files collection. you can even window.URL or fetch a blob to use FileReader() on the ajax response for consistency or mock testing.

Comment: That got complicated quick. t.t